# Annihilators of elements in symmetric algebras

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $M$ be a module over a commutative ring, and $S(M)$ its symmetric algebra. What elements of $S(M)$ annihilate a given element $m\in M$ ? ($M$ is considered as a submodule of $S(M)$.)

Comment: Def. symmetric algebra?

Comment: @user1 $S(M)$ is the quotient of $T(M)$ by the two-sided ideal generated by the commutators $\{x\otimes y−y\otimes x\}_{x,y∈M}$, 
it solves the universal problem of factoring the (linear) arrows from the category of $R$-modules to the one of $R$-commutative associative algebras with unit.

Comment: Let's say, $M$ is a module over $R$.  Now, an annihilator of $m$ in $R$ is clearly part of $S(M)$ and annihilates $M$.  So the ideal of $S(M)$ generated by the $Ann_R(M)$ annihilates $M$.  Is there anything more?

Comment: @user43326 In fact, one can annihilate a specific element $m$ without annihilating $M$, for example take $$R=\mathbb{Q}[\epsilon]=\mathbb{Q}\oplus\mathbb{Q}\epsilon$$ (the dual numbers $\epsilon^2=0$) and $M=R$ then the annihilator of $\epsilon$ is $\mathbb{Q}\epsilon$ whereas the annihilator of $M$ within $S(M)$ is different. Note that, if $R$ is a field, $S(M)$ has no zero divisor.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $Ann_R(m)$.  If $R$ is a field, then $Ann_R(m)$ is also trivial.

Comment: @user43326 OK. Have you an idea of the variation of $Ann_{S(M)}(m)$ with $m\in M$ ? maybe it is known ? (not by me when $R$ is not a field.)

Comment: Do you suppose $M\rightarrow M\otimes _RM$, and similar maps are injective?  Then I can't imagine how $Ann_{S(M)}m$ can contain anything more than the ideal of $S(M)$ generated by $Ann_R(m)$.  If we don't suppose the injectivity, then I have no idea on how $Ann_{S(M)}(n)$ would look like.

Comment: @user43326.  The map $M\to M\otimes_R M$ need not be injective.  For instance, if $R$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ and $M$ is $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, then the target module is the zero module, and the map is the zero map.

Comment: Actually we may not even have such a map, since there is no reason to have a map from $R$ to $M$.  Sorry about that.

Comment: As the mapping $t\rightarrow t.m$ is graded (of degree $d=1$) its kernel, $Ann_{S(M)}(m)$ is graded _i.e._ $$Ann_{S(M)}(m)=\bigoplus_{k\geq 0} Ann_{S(M)}^{(k)}(m)$$ with $$Ann_{S(M)}^{(k)}(m)=Ann_{S(M)}(m)\cap S_k(M)\ .$$ Can each component $Ann_{S(M)}^{(k)}(m)$ be expressed in terms of $Ann_{S(M)}^{(1)}(m)$ ? (precisely the kernel of $t\rightarrow t.m;\ t\in M$.)

Comment: For the first step it is interesting to find the kernel of the map M → M⊗M, sending x from  M to x⊗m, where m is fixed.